# Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS-SDK gem for S3 support on paperclip 3.0.1 and rails 3.2

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

I'm migrating my app from Rails 3.0.9 to 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3. I was using paperclip(2.3.11) with aws-s3 gem to store my pictures.

Now I want to use the last version of paperclip(3.0.1) and then I have to use aws-sdk gem.

I've set my aws.yml file as:

```
    development: &development
      bucket: bucket_name_for_dev
      access_key_id: *****
      secret_access_key: *******
    staging:
      <<: *development
      bucket: bucket_name_for_staging

    production:
      <<: *development
      bucket: bucket_name_for_prod
```

my model contains :

```
    has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "50x50>" }, :default_url => 'picture_missing.png',
         :storage => :s3,
         :bucket => "bucket_name_for_dev",
         :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/aws.yml"),
         :path => "/presentation_pictures/:id/:style/:filename",
         :url  => ":s3_eu_url"

    attr_accessible :picture
    attr_accessor :picture_url
```

When trying to upload a file, I get the error:

`AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch`
`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

I verified that my keys are accessible and set to the right value.

Here is also what I get from console:

```
    [paperclip] Saving attachments.
    [paperclip] saving /presentation_pictures/43/original/Image_1.png
    [AWS S3 200 0.813272 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"*******_dev",:content_type=>"image/png",:data=>#<Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter:0x2e144b4 @target=#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x2dbb1fc @original_filename="Image 1.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"presentation_picture[picture]\"; filename=\"Image 1.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/tb/tbmv4LE9EwGNPr1QqU2S0E+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20120407-33502-1gajfe9>>, @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/tb/tbmv4LE9EwGNPr1QqU2S0E+++TI/-Tmp-/Image 1.png20120407-33502-an4dcy>>,:key=>"presentation_pictures/43/original/Image_1.png")
```

Do you have any idea from where could come this problem?
Thx

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but you could post your aws-sdk and aws-s3 versions from Gemfile.lock?  I'm trying to figure out why this started happening for me too.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. It turned out I was using the correct access key id but my secret key was copied incorrectly.

Double checking my secret key and correcting it fixed it for me.

Comment: Yep... 2x-click, copy and paste can lead to funny results AWS uses characters that break up the key as separate words.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was taking the **root** access key instead of the **user** access key. AWS changed it recently so you must create an individual AIM user for yourself, and then use that user's access key (not root)

Comment: Yeah, creating a non root user did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you cannot access your aws the right way. You have to specify your host name, especially when using buckets in a non US region. Try using

```
:s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

in your `has_attached_file` options.

If you've configured your S3 to use https also add

```
:s3_protocol => 'https'
```

if not, just ignore it.

And if your bucket is a private one, add

```
:s3_permissions => :private
```

You also don't need to explicitly configure your bucket in the options parameter, as you've already declared it in your aws.yml and set it via `:s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/aws.yml")`.

Hope this helps.